# When to NOT use an afci breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, afci, renovation

I'm heading a bunch of renovation done on an old house (1950), and part of the work is rewiring. New panel going in, new NM cable, etc. I should mention this is a pretty small house with no garage, just the basics all under one roof.

The electrician will be doing most of the work, but I've been curious about NEC codes and doing some research, and it seems like the code says you need an afci breaker for every room in the house (laundry, kitchen, bathroom, bedroom), but it doesn't just ever SAY you need afci for every room.

I've got no issues with the added protection or cost, just wondering is it overkill to have nothing but afci breakers? And what about combo afci/gfci breakers?

Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly, when AFCI was phased in, there were no combos, so the GFCI required areas were not on the first AFCI required areas list. I'm not sure where they are at now. Note that for 120V circuits, if you extend in metallic conduit from the panel to a metal box, you can have AFCI **protection** less expensively than AFCI **breakers** with a "deadfront" AFCI device, and then transition to NM out of that box.

Comment: GFCI is used mainly near water/moisture.  6 feet from sinks, outside, basements, ect. they are required.  AFCI required for most other rooms.  This having to do it with new code.  Fridges/freezers should be on dedicated circuits, so you have a chance to just use plain breakers, if the inspector will allow it.  Fridges have been known to have problems with gfci.  Some do not, but you don't want to waste food to find out.